# Trying to parse xml list without parent node using NSxmlparser

Tags: iphone, xml, nsxmlparser

I have already read about NSxmlparser. I have the following file, but I do not understand how I should do for the parser.

i Trying to parse xml list without parent node using NSxmlparser

```
<nodes1>
            <child1>txt1</child1>
            <child2>Txt2</child2>
</nodes1>
<nodes1>
            <child1>Txt3</child1>
            <child2>Txt4</child2>
</nodes1>
<nodes1>
            <child1>Txt5</child1>
            <child2>Txt6</child2>
</nodes1>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I am in the process of development, but I plant what I should write here

`- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString 
*)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the file and start parsing

```
NSError *error;
NSString *xmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFile" ofType:@"xml"];

NSString* contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
self.xmlData = [[NSData alloc] init];
self.xmlData = [contents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:self.xmlData];
[self.xmlParser setDelegate: self];
[self.xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
[self.xmlParser parse];
```

then for parsing

```
BOOL isValid_child1 = NO;

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
      if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"child1"]) {
      isValid_child1 = YES; 
      }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (isValid_child1) {
        valueInChild1 = string; // string is txt1
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"child1"]) {
       isValid_child1 = NO;
       [array addObject:valueInChild1]; // to add value for child1 to an array
    }
```

I know this is dirty ;) but it works, you can do it more flexible.

Comment: thank you. and about the child 2 i should add 
`if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"child2"]) isValid_child2 = YES;`

Comment: yes this is right. You can do this also with nodes1 to determine that you in nodes1->child1

Comment: if i want to save the result into array i add this code `tab[i]=string; i++;`  into function  `foundCharacters`

Comment: for example yes, or you can in didEndElement if the right element [array addObject: valueInChild1];